# Segmentation fault when colmap gui

Tags: segmentation-fault, qt5, ubuntu-18.04, colmap

I'm trying to use colmap on ubuntu-18.04, and the `cmake` and `make install` went smoothly. Using the command `colmap -h` also worked fine. However, when I use the `colmap gui` command, I encounter the following error:

```
zhangzb@master:~$ /home/zhangzb/Colmap/bin/colmap gui
*** Aborted at 1695538937 (unix time) try "date -d @1695538937" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0xd8) received by PID 184121 (TID 0x7f96c48ae000) from PID 216; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f968e0f4980 (unknown)
    @     0x55b787a325a8 colmap::ModelViewerWidget::initializeGL()
    @     0x7f968cec071d QOpenGLWidgetPrivate::initialize()
    @     0x7f968cec085a QOpenGLWidget::resizeEvent()
    @     0x7f968cea1cbe QWidget::event()
    @     0x7f968ce6392c QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper()
    @     0x7f968ce6ab10 QApplication::notify()
    @     0x7f968bf8e348 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2()
    @     0x7f968ce9a81d QWidgetPrivate::sendPendingMoveAndResizeEvents()
    @     0x7f968ce9e123 QWidgetPrivate::show_helper()
    @     0x7f968cea12d7 QWidgetPrivate::setVisible()
    @     0x7f968ce9e0d0 QWidgetPrivate::showChildren()
    @     0x7f968ce9e13f QWidgetPrivate::show_helper()
    @     0x7f968cea12d7 QWidgetPrivate::setVisible()
    @     0x55b78784d9f7 colmap::RunGraphicalUserInterface()
    @     0x55b78781bc93 main
    @     0x7f968af87c87 __libc_start_main
    @     0x55b787822f5a _start
    @                0x0 (unknown)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is it because my Qt version is incompatible?

```
zhangzb@master:~$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /home/zhangzb/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/gcc_64/lib
```